# How do I put array into columns

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $db = mysql_connect("", "", "") or die("Could not connect.");
mysql_select_db("",$db)or die(mysql_error()); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table where 1";
$pager = new pager($sql,'page',6);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pager->result))
{
    echo $row['persons']."<br>";
}
 mysql_close($db);
```

above code output :

Mathew
Thomas
John
Stewart
Watson
Kelvin

What I need is it should split inot multiple columns say:

Mathew   Stewart
Thomas   Watson
John     Kelvin

HOw do I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$columnCount = 2;
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pager->result))
{
     $newRow = ( $i % $columnCount == 0 );
     if( $newRow ) {
        echo '<tr>';
     }
     echo '<td>' . $row['persons'] . '</td>';
     if( $newRow ) {  
        echo '</tr>';
     }
     $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: great but how do I put it in a neat table??

Comment: oops one more question if I need in three columns then??